# Moving a single key value pair from one dictionary to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on building out a basic store in python, with a dictionary of items and their prices. I'm using a dictionary for the cart, and I want users to be able to add items to the cart. For this, I'm aiming to copy a key and value from the products dictionary to the cart dictionary. How can I do this?

```
products = {"Pencil": 1, "Notebook": 2, "Backpack": 3, "Pens": 2, "Markers": 5, "Whiteboard": 30}
cart = {}

def addToCart():
    productToAdd = input("What would you like to add? ")
    for k,v in products.items():
        if productToAdd == k:
            price = v
            cart[productToAdd] = cart[v]
            break
```

Comment: change  `cart[productToAdd] = cart[v]` to `cart[productToAdd] = products[k]`

Comment: You can change `cart[productToAdd] = cart[v]` to `cart[productToAdd] = price`.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to completely remove the key from `products` or just "copy" it and its value.

Answer (score 2):

```
products = {"Pencil": 1, "Notebook": 2, "Backpack": 3, "Pens": 2, "Markers": 5, "Whiteboard": 30}
cart = {}

def addToCart():
    try:
        productToAdd = input("What would you like to add? ")
        cart[productToAdd]=products[productToAdd]
    except KeyError:
        print("No such product")
```

Note that python is case sensitive 'pencil' and 'Pencil' are not the same.
If you are sure the products are meant to be Capital-letter first you can use

```
productToAdd = input("What would you like to add? ").title()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that user will choose items from that list(particularly from keys) then:

```
products = {"Pencil": 1, "Notebook": 2, "Backpack": 3, "Pens": 2, "Markers": 5, 
"Whiteboard": 30}

cart = {}


def addToCart():
    productToAdd = input("What would you like to add? ")
    if not productToAdd.title() in products: # for removing caps confusion
        print('No such item')
    else: cart[productToAdd] = products[productToAdd]


>>> addToCart()
What would you like to add? Pencil
>>> cart
{'Pencil': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `dict.setdefault(key, default=None)`
Example:

```
def addToCart():
    productToAdd = input("What would you like to add? ")
    cart[productToAdd]=products.setdefault(productToAdd, 'No such product')
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to use raw_input or it would not take in the string such as 'Pencil'.
This is how you copy key value pairs.

```
products = {"Pencil": 1, "Notebook": 2, "Backpack": 3, "Pens": 2, "Markers": 5, "Whiteboard": 30}

cart = {}

def addToCart():
    productToAdd = raw_input("What would you like to add? ")
    for k,v in products.items():
        print(k)
        if productToAdd == k:
            cart[k] = v
            break

addToCart()
print(cart)
```

Comment: Its python3 not python2, `raw_input` is only needed for python2

Comment: Good catch. I would go with the try catch answer given. Safer if user gives an invalid product.

Comment: Agreed, the question was more about inserting a new item into a dictionary, over how he is pulling them out of the old dictionary.

Comment: @mtngt Ok, but I think that if there is a way to take OPs code from `O(n)` down to `O(1)` it should definitely be noted, especially if that way is half the length.